# Creating a vector of values based off a test using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

This feels like it should be a simple problem but I am newer to python, in R i would use a foreach loop that gave me an option to combine.

I have tried a for loop that lets me print out all the values i need but i want them collected into a vector of values that i can use later.

```py
from scipy.stats import gamma
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import random

data2 = np.random.gamma(1,2, size = 500)

gammT =  np.log(data2 + 1)

mean = np.mean(gammT)
sd = np.std(gammT)

a = (mean/ sd)**2
b = (sd**2)/ mean

for i in range(1,100):
    gammT = random.sample(list(gammT), 500)
    gamm = np.random.gamma(a,b, size = len(gammT))
    s = stats.anderson_ksamp([gammT,gamm])
    s = s[2]
    print(s)
```

So i am able to print all the values i want but i want them all to be gathered together in a vector of values. I have tried to append and make lists but am not able to get them together.

Comment: `range(1,100):`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example @clinton, data2.iscore is undefined

Comment: I now have it with reproducible code and range i am used to getting a string of numbers in R using 1:100, i overlooked while typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import random

gammT =  np.log(data2.iScore + 1)

mean = np.mean(gammT)
sd = np.std(gammT)

a = (mean/ sd)**2
b = (sd**2)/ mean

#initialize empty list
result=[]

for i in range(100): 
# removed (1,100) you only need range(100) for 100 elements
    gammT = random.sample(list(gammT), 500)
    gamm = np.random.gamma(a,b, size = len(gammT))
    s = stats.anderson_ksamp([gammT,gamm])
    s = s[2]
    #append calculation to list
    result.append(s)
    print(s)
print(result)
```